# PySide: How to set a custom QMessageBox size?

Tags: python, pyside, qt4.8

I am working with PySide on the Raspberry PI + PiTFT, making a kiosk style (ie, fullscreen) style app.

I'm restricted to 320x240 pixels - and having a very hard time forcing message boxes to a specifc size.

Ultimately, I am wanting to make a *fullscreen, on-top* message box / dialog.

I've considered using the code:
[How to allow resizing of QMessageBox in PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655354/how-to-allow-resizing-of-qmessagebox-in-pyqt4)
But this hooks on *every* event, and paints artefacts on the screen.

What is the best / better way to creating on-top, full screen messageboxes ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of suggestions out there for resizing QMessageBox's and I tried most of them - for me they didn't work. What did work was to get a handle on the underlying QGridLayout and set the minimum sizes there.

```
class myMsgBox(QtGui.QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.findChild(QtGui.QGridLayout).setColumnMinimumWidth(1, 700)
        ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

def messageBox(msg, text, informtext):
msg.setText(text)
msg.setInformativeText(informtext)
msg.findChild(QGridLayout).setColumnMinimumWidth(1, len(msg.informativeText()) * msg.fontMetrics().averageCharWidth())
msg.exec()