# How to resize QMessageBox in Python 3.5, PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I have a QMessageBox that is too short.

I've tried various methods of increasing the height, such as *resize, setMinimumHeight, setSizeIncrement + setSizeGripEnabled*, but none of these attempts work. Setting SizeGrip doesn't allow me to resize the window at all.

```
dialog = QMessageBox(self)

dialog.setWindowTitle('About this programme')
dialog.setText('Introductory text')
dialog.setDetailedText('A bunch more text')

dialog.setMinimumHeight(500)
dialog.setSizeIncrement(1, 1)
dialog.setSizeGripEnabled(True)

dialog.show()
```

For reference in the picture, the window labelled Rotascript has size 360x, 370y.

What am I doing wrong, or is this some kind of bug?

Thanks in advance.

[image: Screen is a 27" 1080p display]

Comment: Did u test `dialog.reSize()` ?

Comment: I don't think neither pyqt5 nor python-3.x makes this not a duplicate of many earlier posts, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655354/how-to-allow-resizing-of-qmessagebox-in-pyqt4), or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668820/how-can-i-resize-qmessagebox).

Answer (score 5):

You're not doing anything wrong.  The `QMessageBox` is notoriously difficult to resize.

Generally, people use one of three approaches:

1. Use `setText()` with newlines instead of `setInformativeText()`

   The message box will resize with respect to the text set by the `setText()` method.  It's hacky, but you could simply include a bunch of white space in `setText()`.
2. Try overriding the layout of `QMessageBox`

   This is includes fiddling with `setFixedSize` or overriding the widget's `event` method.  Here is [a good example from a related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2664019/5065796).
3. Reimplement `QMessageBox`

   A fundamental property of `QMessageBox` is that it doesn't resize.  So, through backwards logic, [if you want a message box which resizes, you actually don't want a message box](https://youtu.be/9Jz1TjCphXE).  However, the `QMessageBox` inherits from `QDialog`.  You might be able to achieve what you want by going up a level in the inheritance chain and re-implementing the features you want from a `QDialog`.

The following resources informed my response:

- [apocalyptech.com - Qt5 Resizing a QMessageBox](https://web.archive.org/web/20190910202435/http://apocalyptech.com/linux/qt/qmessagebox/)
- [How to allow resizing of QMessageBox in PyQt4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655354/how-to-allow-resizing-of-qmessagebox-in-pyqt4)
- [How can I resize QMessageBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668820/how-can-i-resize-qmessagebox)

Answer (score 1):

In PySide6 this worked for me:

```
dialog.findChild(QGridLayout).setColumnMinimumWidth(1,len(dialog.informativeText()) * dialog.fontMetrics().averageCharWidth())
```

Comment: *"Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try to mention any limitations, assumptions or simplifications in your answer. Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better."* - check [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).